# Problem when setting 2D Nav Goal [closed]

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap, global-costmap, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm running `ROS Kinetic` in Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS on a Raspberry Pi 3.
My navigation stack is up and running and my robot is able to localize itself in a given map. I'm also able to drive around via a joystick (`/input_joy/cmd_vel`-topic).
The next step is to [drive around in rviz](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals). I am able to set 2D Pose Estimates there, but whenever I'm trying to set a 2D Nav Goal, nothing is happening, except from the arrow and the path being visually displayed in rviz.
Unfortunately, when echoing the `/cmd_vel`-topic, which is being published by `move_base`, it always displays the following:

```
linear: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: -1.0
```

As well I get the following error thrown until I kill `move_base`:

```
Control loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.4580 seconds
```

Since I don't get that error, before setting a 2D Nav Goal, I assume that there is either something wrong in one of my costmaps or move_base settings...

I appreciate all your help. Thanks in advance.
Nico

---

### base_local_planner_params.yaml

```
TrajectoryPlannerROS:
  max_vel_x: 0.19
  min_vel_x: 0.095
  max_vel_theta: 0.256
  min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.192

  acc_lim_theta: 3.2
  acc_lim_x: 2.5
  acc_lim_y: 2.5

  holonomic_robot: true
  meter_scoring: true
```

---

### costmap_common_params.yaml

```
plugins:
  - {name: static_map,      type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
  - {name: obstacles,       type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}
  - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}

obstacle_range: 2.5
raytrace_range: 3.0
footprint: [[0.05, 0.05], [0.05, -0.05],[0, -0.10]]
#robot_radius: 0.20
inflation_radius: 0.55

obstacles:
  observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
  laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: laser, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

---

### global_costmap_params.yaml

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: /map
  robot_base_frame: base
  update_frequency: 0.8
  static_map: false
  width: 5
  height: 2
```

---

### local_costmap_params.yaml

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base
  update_frequency: 1.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 3.0
  height: 3.0
  resolution: 0.05
controller_frequency: 5.0
```

---

### move_base.launch

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/project/launch/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/project/launch/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/project/launch/config/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/project/launch/config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/project/launch/config/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

### rqt_graph

[rqt_graph on imgur](https://imgur.com/a/ZznpN)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260335/problem-when-setting-2d-nav-goal-%5Bclosed%5D/) by [nico_b](https://answers.ros.org/users/28930/nico_b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-04-27**:
Please add the rosgraph. According to the /cmd_vel output your robot must drive clockwise, but you said your robots listens to /input_joy/cmd_vel, so its either /cmd_vel or /input_joy/cmd_vel.

**Comment by [nico_b](https://answers.ros.org/users/28930/nico_b/) on 2017-04-27**:
I just added the rqt_graph... Thanks in advance

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-04-27**:
In global_costmap_params.yaml the static_map should be true.

**Comment by [nico_b](https://answers.ros.org/users/28930/nico_b/) on 2017-04-27**:
Ok, I changed that, but still my problem stays the same...

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-04-27**:
In addition to the static_map for the global_costmap_params.yaml, also make sure that your robot IS holonomic and if it's not, set that to false in base_local_planner_params.yaml. I would guess that your robot is NOT holonomic, since holonomic robots are not that widespread with RPi implementations.

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-04-27**:
Also, try adding this `controller_frequency: 3.0` in base_local_planner_params.yaml.

**Comment by [nico_b](https://answers.ros.org/users/28930/nico_b/) on 2017-04-27**:
Thanks a lot, guys, the problem is solved... I got some bad values set in my `base_local_planner_params.yaml`-file, which didn't fit that robot.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To sum up what was said in the comments for future readers, nico_b had to:

1. Change holonomic_robot to false in base_local_planner_params.yaml.
2. Lower the control frequency to 3Hz (due to RPi3's low computing power) in base_local_planner_params.yaml.
3. Change static_map to true in global_costmap_params.yaml.

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2017-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) on 2017-04-27**:
You can now close your question. Happy coding! :)